# How do "transform into" and "turn into" function syntactically?

Tags: syntax, english, verbs, parts-of-speech, prepositions

> He turned into a car

> He transformed into a car

What are the syntactic categories of "transform", "turn", and "into" in each sentence?

I think that "turned into" is a copular phrasal verb. The "into" is thus not a preposition.

However, these fail to some extent the pronomilization test for phrasal verbhood ("he turned it into" doesn't mean the same thing, but neither does "he turned it") so perhaps "into ..." is a prepositional phrase attaching extra information about the result of "He transformed." Some dictionaries list "turn into" as a phrasal verb though.

What are the actual possible correct ways of syntactically tagging these two sentences?

Comment: _Transform into_ in this sense is used only in comix, so any usage is OK. _Turn into_ is ambiguous and can also refer to movement on a path (_She turned into Elm Street_). In modern American English, _change into_ is used more often in this sense, though it can also refer to changing clothes. Both of these ambiguous constructions are the basis for jokes (this is comix, after all). But _transform into_ is a mark of comic-style fantasy, a la the Transformers.

Comment: _Turn_ can be intransitive as well, but it is more limited than _transform_. Apart from tides, it can also refer to switching between good and evil, gay and straight, etc. – though not between human and car form, generally. @jlawler _Transform into_ is also a common mark of Attenborough-esque documentaries: “The caterpillar is now fully transformed into a butterfly and emerges from its cocoon”, etc. Though I suppose a caterpillar transforming into a car would have to be a _very_ niche subtype of Attenborough-esque comic-style fantasy.